Using an encrypted key in R targets pipeline?
I am using encrypted data that feeds into my targets pipline. My _targets.R script loads the key (created from the cyphr package), which allows it to decrypt my data files. However, targets pipeline always views the key object as outdated, so it runs the entire pipeline everytime. Is there a workaround for this or another method you would suggest for working with encrypted data when using the targets package?
My _targets.R file has the following structure:
library(targets)
library(tarchetypes)
library(cyphr) 
library(here) 

key_dir <- here("./")
key <- cyphr::data_key(key_dir, path_user = key_dir)
redcap_data_path <- here("./data/redcap_data.RDS")

list(
  tar_target(redcap_data,
    cyphr::decrypt(readRDS(redcap_data_path), key = key)
  ),
  tar_target(processed_data,
    some_function_to_process_data(redcap_data)
  )
) |> 
  tar_hook_outer(hook = encrypt_object(.x, key = key)) |>
  tar_hook_inner(hook = decrypt_object(.x, key = key))

I am hoping to find a method that would allow the key to be used without it being considered outdated by the targets package and thus resulting all of the downstream pipeline to also be considered outdated.
I tried loading the key itself as a target, but it threw an error: "no applicable method for 'store_class_format' applied to an object of class "c('NA', 'character')"
